# Hp Pavillon zv5000 hard disk problem

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I have this laptop and the disk was not working and very noisy so I thought to change it.
I've bought a new one and mounted it and when I do the hd autotest in bios I get a:

> `07 - failed`

What could I do?
What could it be?

Motherboard fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem: the disk was unformatted so the bios test threw an error.

As soon as I've formatted the disk (of course without problems) also the bios test was fine.

I panicked because I didn't have, at the 1st time, an operating system with me so the only thing I could do to test the disc was using bios diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the motherboard or maybe the on-board controller, but it also could be that by extremely bad luck the new disk is also bad.

A repair shop would have all the tools required to figure-out the problem.